# How do I access this rss variable inside my fetch method in React Native?

Tags: react-native, rss, fetch, expo, rss-reader

I'm trying to use `react-native-rss-parser` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rss-parser) to parse my RSS feed and display it on a card but I don't know how to access the `rss` variable.

```
fetchRSSFeed() {
    return fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
    .then((rss) =>  { console.log(rss.title) })
  }

render() {
      {this.fetchRSSFeed()}
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Swiper
            cards={HomeScreenPics}
            renderCard={Card}
            infinite 
            backgroundColor="white"
            cardHorizontalMargin={0}
            stackSize={2} 
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }
  }

  HomeScreenPics = [{
    pic: require('../assets/images/news.jpg'), 
    title: rss.title
  }]
```

`console.log(rss.title)` works fine. It logs out the RSS feed title but I'm trying to access the `rss` varible outside the fetch method, I want to parse it into my `HomeScreenPics` array, but it keeps showing the error: Can't find variable rss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the rss variable and pass it to the render function, all you have to do is to use the state that react provides you.

Example:

```
state = {
   feed: {}
}

fetchRSSFeed() {
    return fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
    .then((rss) =>  { 
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            feed: rss
        }));
    })
  }

render() {
      {this.fetchRSSFeed()}
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Swiper
            cards={HomeScreenPics}
            renderCard={Card}
            infinite 
            backgroundColor="white"
            cardHorizontalMargin={0}
            stackSize={2} 
          />
        <Text>{this.state.feed.title}</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }
  }
```

You can access the response object with the variable `this.state.feed`in any function.

I recommend you to start from the official documentation: [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state]

Friendly.

Comment: I do have one more question, how do I parse it into my `HomeScreenPics =  [{ title: feed.title }]` ?

Comment: It's showing `Cant find variable: feed` when I try to parse it into my `HomeScreenPics` array

Comment: @DarkLord666 By the time the images you want to render are based on the fetch response you should put the whole array `HomeScreenPics` inside the react state. Dont forget that every time the state is updated the render function re-executes.

Comment: Cant find varibale: feed

Answer (score 0):

I am actually facing the same issue as you had. xarhsasi answers works like a charm.
Bear in mind that you can avoid calling the function each time since you are willing to render it once, just at the beginning.
I strongly recommend you to add it into a componentDidMount(), like so

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      feed: {}
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss')
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
    .then((rss) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          feed: rss
        });
        
      });
  }
```

Then, you only need to call the state like xarhsasi told you with `this.state.feed.title`, for example.

Best regards,